# Associate .ps1 to powershell.exe through domain GPO on 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, powershell, extension, file-associations

I need to associate .ps1 with powershell.exe instead of Notepad via GPO from a 2008r2 DC.  I've seen one question mention CSE under Computer Configuration\Preferences\Control Panel Settings\Folder Options and setting it there.  But I'm not sure exactly what to do and I can't find anything helpful anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.  Under Folder Options, Right Click in the main part of the area and go to New -> File Type

```
Action: Create
File extension: .ps1
Check Configure Class Settings
Under Action -> New
Action: Open
Application: *Path to Powershell*
```

Then OK/Save out.

Reference: [TechNet: Configure a File Type Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754587.aspx)

**EDIT:** Can't find the class, and I even used PowerShell to extract that dropdown list and search it...nothing.

There is a way to set it via Registry in Group Policy.  The class is Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1 and full path to it is:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command
```

Change the (Default) value to:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-file" "%1"
```

This is found in the GPOE:

```
\Computer Configuration\Preferences\Windows Settings\Registry
```

**SUMMARY:** Create a new Registry Item:

```
Settings:
  Action: Update
  Hive: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  Key Path: Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command
  Value name: Check Default
  Value type: REG_SZ
  Value data: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-file" "%1"
```

Then wait for GP flush on machines.

Comment: It's asking for an associated class.  What should I put there?

Comment: Touche.  I can't find the class in the list.  You can always just directly modify the registry using Group Policy.  Interested?

Comment: Sure.  Give me a rundown in an edit on your answer.

Comment: Brilliant.  I'll test this and mark appropriately.